# Admin Panel - Custom Menu Sub-Item LINK

Tags: customization, wp-admin, admin-menu, sub-menu, add-submenu-page

I'm trying to add a custom link under my Post Type in my admin menu, which will link to Pending Posts. This code functions, but it instead makes a page (like I suppose the function should), but I just need a single link and there doens't seem to be a `add_submenu_link` function unfortunately. Is there a way to create a static link but place it in my post type submenu?

```
/** Add Pending Posts to WP Admin Menu **/
function add_custom_link() {
    add_submenu_page('edit.php?post_type=cpt_custom', '', 'Pending Posts', 5, __FILE__, 'sub_page_pending');
}
function sub_page_pending() {
  echo '<li><a href="edit.php?post_status=pending&post_type=cpt_custom">Pending Posts</a></li>';
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'add_custom_link');
```

I've tried to use a `wp_redirect()` but I get some errors telling me that the headers have already been set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert the URL of the page as the `$menu_slug` argument. Also note that user levels are deprecated, you should pass a [capability](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Capabilities) instead.

```
function add_custom_link() {
    add_submenu_page(
        'edit.php?post_type=cpt_custom',
        '',
        'Pending Posts',
        'edit_posts',
        'edit.php?post_type=cpt_custom&post_status=pending',
        ''
    );
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'add_custom_link');
```

Comment: The link kept going to my root, so I had to add a `/` at the front of my link, but it works!